# document.getElementById returns null when element is part of a form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have `php` file that has some javascript inside. Consider the following javascript code, which prints `null` to the console (line 124 in the file):

```
console.log(document.getElementById('d_min'));
```

Below the script, I have the following form (line 140 in the file):

```
<FORM name="DataCollect" ACTION="save_phase1.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="d_min" id="d_min" value=""/>
</FORM>
```

Why is it that it could be `null`? Why can't it find that element?

---

I FIXED THE PROBLEM:

I put the entire `<form>` as a `document.write` statement after the existing `document.write` statements I had.

Comment: Either it is because you have placed the code to early in your file / not within `window.load` or you have a duplicate ID.

Comment: Placed which code too early in the file? I don't have a window.load function. It is not a duplicate ID

Comment: Where did you put `document.getElementById('d_min')`? Is that within a `script` tag in the `head`? As mentioned in the answers (and my comment) you need to either place it after the form or within `window.onload`

Comment: You can see the full file. there is a link in the question. I did place it after the form and it still was null. I put the form at the beginning of the <body> tag (as per my comments in another answer) and it is the same output (null).

Comment: You have some strange HTML. Your `<title>` and `<link ...>` should be within `<head>` and all content such as `<div id="welcome"...` should be within `<body>`.

Comment: I'm a pretty big noob to html, javascript, php, etc. So yeah, it's a mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DOM` is not fully loaded by the time the script executes.  Move your script below that form and see if you get better results.

Comment: I put the <form> at the very beginning of the <body> tag and it still prints out null.

Comment: That is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the JavaScript code in `window.onload` function.

Comment: well, basically the part when you operate on DOM elements, so you can try only this piece: console.log(document.getElementById('d_min'));

Comment: but the part with DOM is being called wayyy before the document.getElementById

Comment: are you 100% sure of that? did you try to put it into window.onload ?

Comment: Yes, the document.getElementById('d_min') is the very last thing that is called. I wrapped all my javascript in window.onload but then it said it could not find the startTest() function

Comment: Wait by DOM do you mean the document.write calls?

Comment: if you could put it into jsfiddle, it'd be great. It doesn't matter if you put js code BEFORE html code. The thing is, script may be called (so start executing) before DOM tree is fuly rendered, hence elements you're refering to may still be not in the actual page. For wait for DOM to be fully loaded, I mean put it into window.onload function

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it's not grabbing the field, but try giving the form an id `foo` and using

```
document.getElementById('foo').d_min
```

instead. At least it will narrow the source of the problem.